# Showing Financial Transaction Data with Contributions

Tags: contributions, drupal-views

I have created a drupal view of contributions. In this view i want it to show:

1. Date Contribution Created (CiviCRM Contributions: Date Received)
2. Financial Type (CiviCRM Contributions: Financial Type)
3. Fee Amount(CiviCRM Contributions: Fee Amount)
4. Net Amount (CiviCRMContributions: Net Amount)
5. ***Payment Date*** - This is the only data i can't extract as this is linked to the financial Transaction. I need the transaction date

I have added a relationship "CiviCRM Contributions: CiviCRM Line items" but it pulls in other transnational data not the txrn date.

When i create a view of "CiviCRM Financial Trxn" I am unable to add in a relationship therefore unable to pull in contributions data.

Any Ideas?

---

I have thought about putting a View within a View to pull that data and it works unfortunately it shows a duplication of the contribution as there is several financial transaction entries for that contribution.

Thanks

Comment: I would think Views Field View would potentially help. when you say you get 'several financial transactions' is there nothing you can do in the other view to filter to just the one you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no relationship being handled in views between contribution and payment(financial trxn table). You can do this by writing a small module implementing [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7.x-3.x) hook with civicrm entity module.